# Evaluate $\lim_{x\to0} \frac{\sqrt{2-x}-\sqrt{2}}{x}$.

Tags: calculus, limits

(Didn't really know what to title the question, sorry for that)

So I've got the following limit:

> $$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\sqrt{2-x}-\sqrt2}{x}$$

So I thought I would figure out the right and left hand limits to see if it exists, to which I got $-\infty$ and $\infty$ respectively. However, WolframAlpha [tells me otherwise](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=lim+y%3D%28sqrt%282-x%29-sqrt2%29%2Fx) (*sigh*).

So obviously my reasoning isn't right because both values (numerator and denominator) become really small as x approaches zero, so it should approach some value. But I don't have any idea about how to find that value (other than look it up).
So obviously my reasoning isn't right because both values (numerator and denominator) become really small as x approaches zero

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Hint:** Multiply top and bottom by $\sqrt{2-x}+\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: You are welcome.